# How to change background color using SwingBuilder?

Tags: java, groovy

I would like to change color of background using `SwingBuilder` in Groovy.

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

import java.awt.BorderLayout
import java.awt.Color
import java.awt.Font

class BackgroundWork {
    static void main(String[] args) {

        def background = new Color(155, 155, 110)
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.SERIF, 17)
        def swing = new SwingBuilder()
        swing.edt {
            frame(title: 'Prosty edytor', size: [200, 200], show: true) {
                borderLayout()
                textArea(id: 'TextArea', lineWrap: true, wrapStyleWord: true, columns: 50, rows: 5, editable: true, background: background).setFont(font)
                button(text: 'Click me', constraints: BorderLayout.SOUTH, actionPerformed: {
                    background = java.awt.Color.RED
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `SwingBuilder` with simple frame. How to refresh data `onClick`?

EDIT

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'background' on null object
```

Comment: If this edit is in regard to my answer, then my _guess_ is, that you are doing `def ta = textArea(...).setFont(...)`, which will not work since you are assigning the result of `setFont` (which is nil). You would have to rewrite that like e.g. `def ta = textArea(...).tap{ setFont(...) }`

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the wrong background.  If you set just background to
a new color, you are replacing the assignment to background and not the
background of your text area.

You can change the background by keeping hold of the created text area
and then assign the background on it.

E.g.

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

import java.awt.BorderLayout
import java.awt.Color

class BackgroundWork {
    static void main(String[] args) {

        def background = new Color(155, 155, 110)
        def swing = new SwingBuilder()
        swing.edt {
            frame(title: 'Prosty edytor', size: [200, 200], show: true) {
                borderLayout()
                // XXX
                def ta = textArea(id: 'TextArea', lineWrap: true, wrapStyleWord: true, columns: 50, rows: 5, editable: true, background: background)
                button(text: 'Click me', constraints: BorderLayout.SOUTH, actionPerformed: {
                    // XXX
                    ta.background = java.awt.Color.RED
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to have as well font to set, why you have deleted it, can I implement it other way?

Comment: Your code did not work and it is not relevant to the question - so i have removed it.